# What's the preferred way to close a psycopg2 connection used by Python object?

Tags: python, database-connection, psycopg2

I create a database connection in the `__init__` method of a Python class and want to make sure that the connection is closed on object destruction.
It looks like I can do this in `__del__()` or make the class a context manager and close the connection in `__exit__()`. I wonder which one is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like I can do this in `__del__()` or make the class a context manager and close the connection in `__exit__()`. I wonder which one is more Pythonic.

I won't  comment on what's more "pythonic", since that is a **highly** subjective question.

However, Python doesn't make very strict guarantees on when a destructor is called, making the context/`__exit__` approach the right one here.

Comment: I also use context managers to do this.  It works well, but what took a bit of doing was to make sure that all my connections were getting called through a context manager, otherwise you won't release them.  Maybe use \__exit__ **and** \__del__?  I didn't do that - wrote some code to inspect the stack and raise an Exception if it wasn't a context manager call.

Comment: simply don't establish a connection outside the `__enter__` method. Problem solved.

Comment: ah, ah.  clever.  I'll see if I refactor my code to do that.  Otherwise, yes context managers are cool.  Ah, one other thing, they do enforce some constraints on instance lifecycles - my connections get initiated on django views and get terminated when the response is sent.  I had to refactor other classes that tended to hold on to db connections and pass the connection as params to their methods instead.